# Bypass Min SDK Version - or what else?

Tags: flutter, compilation, sdk, version

I am starting with flutter, and overall, I am getting an idea but have hit the wall with what I find to be one of the main reasons to consider migrating from HTML + JQueryMobile: speech to text implementation.

I have found the speech_to_text package (https://pub.dev/packages/speech_to_text#-installing-tab-), followed the instructions to :
1. update the pubspec.yaml file with the dependency &
2. instal the package from command line
3. import the package in the code

but have hit the wall with the minimum SDK requirements not being met by the package. Here is the error message:

> > C:\Users\TOTAL\FlutterPro\Flutter4\flutter4\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml
> >     Error:  uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 21
> >     declared in library [:speech_to_text]
> >     C:\Users\TOTAL\FlutterPro\Flutter4\flutter4\build\speech_to_text\intermediates\library_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml
> >     as the library might be using APIs not available in 16  Suggestion:
> >     use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,       or increase
> >     this project's minSdk version to at least 21,       or use
> >     tools:overrideLibrary="com.csdcorp.speech_to_text" to force usage (may
> >     lead to runtime failures)
> >
> > FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
> >
> > - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> >
> >   > Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 21 declared in library [:speech_to_text]
> >   >       C:\Users\TOTAL\FlutterPro\Flutter4\flutter4\build\speech_to_text\intermediates\library_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml
> >   >       as the library might be using APIs not available in 16      Suggestion:
> >   >       use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
> >   >           or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 21,
> >   >           or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.csdcorp.speech_to_text" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
> > - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> > - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
> >
> > BUILD FAILED in 11s Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with
> >     exit code 1
>
> Strangely, I have managed to bypass this once but can not find the
>    relevant piece of code in the app folder now. Worse, the mentioned file

```
> C:\Users\TOTAL\FlutterPro\Flutter4\flutter4\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml
does not contain any reference to SDK, only this:
< <manifest
 <xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  <   package="com.example.flutter4">
>     <!-- Flutter needs it to communicate with the running application
>          to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
>     -->
>     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> </manifest>

As for the other mentioned file, which looks like this: 


> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <manifest
> xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     package="com.csdcorp.speech_to_text" >
> 
>     <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" />
> 
> </manifest>
```

changing the 21 to 16 is reverted after the attempt to run this app.

How to handle this
1. technically, ie. what is the workaround for this minSDK limitation - one that is at least worth trying?
2. A step back, if there are version issues, how  do you do to avoid them?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Sorry, I was too vague in question 2. If there are such library/package version compatibility issues, there need to be some way to maintain strict standards with regards to updating, ie. no sooner to update flutter than all the authors of critical addons pick up with the update. How do you deal with that? Do you use tools like yarn/other? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the build.gradle file in app folder. Search `defaultConfig`, edit the `minSdkVersion` from 16 to 21.

File path.

```
android\app\build.gradle
```

Comment: This has worked, thank you. Counterintuitive as I would think that raising a minimum could only limit the chances.